# The pentecostal cult from Romania affiliation

Tags: pentecostalism

Is [the Pentecostal cult in Romania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentecostal_Union_of_Romania) affiliated to any international Pentecostal association or organization or movement? If yes, then which one? Do they have a website?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  I went to the Wikipedia link you provided but still don't understand why you have called it "a cult".  Can you explain what you mean by "a cult".  Also, please check out our Tour which explains what we look for in a well researched answer: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @Lesley They appear to nominate themselves as a 'cult' (see the penultimate sentence of the Wiki article) _Banned in 1937, it was revived as Buletinul Cultului Penticostal ("Newsletter of the Pentecostal **Cult"**) in 1953_.

Comment: I used the name they gave themselves, as Nigel rightly observed. A much better translation would be Pentecostal Church of Romania.

Comment: http://www.cultulpenticostal.ro/acasa/.   The official website in your link   Not in English though